# In-Process WMI Provider for a Windows Service in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, wmi

How do you write an in-process WMI provider as part of Windows Service written in .NET?

I've written a provider that uses the de-coupled hosting model as a standalone application, but can't figure out how to get a Windows Service that uses the Hosting Model = ManagementHostingModel.NetworkService to work.

This is the kind of provider I'm using:

```
    [ManagementEntity]
public class Stuff
{
    private readonly string _id;

    public Stuff( string id )
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    [ManagementKey]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    [ManagementProbe]
    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return DateTime.UtcNow; }
    }

    [ManagementEnumerator]
    public static IEnumerable Enumerate()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            yield return new Stuff( i.ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

Which I register using:

```
InstrumentationManager.RegisterType(typeof (Stuff));
```

Every time I try and access the WMI classes when trying to read the property values, I just get some weird exceptions thrown.

It seems like there must be something really simple I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only bit I was missing was that in-process providers must be installed in the GAC. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc268228.aspx) for more details.

Comment: How do you get information about your particular service into the provider?  All the examples I've found provide canned data (like your `Stuff`) or system data (like your `DateTime.UtcNow`, or like a list of running processes).  If the coupled provider is being instantiated and run by the WMI host, then how does it get application-specific data to provide?